# findall in prolog, param goal is: between + member, how to?

Tags: prolog

I have to make a prolog program, and I have to find all combinations that meet those conditions:

... code... function(..., List),
findall(clause, goal, C) 
where goal = (between(1,N,X), member(X, List))

I can't find out how to do it.

It can be with bagof too if anyone knows how.

Comment: just put your goals as you stated, i.e: `findall(X, (between(1,N,X), member(X,List)), C)`. This will unify C with the list of numbers between 1 and N that are contained in List.

Comment: is it the same:
findall( x-A-AS, (between(1,NA,A),member(A,L))
than:
bagof( x-A-AS, between(1,NA,A)^member(A,L), C)
@gusbro

Comment: The constructs you posted make no sense to me. Check the documentation of `findall/3` and `bagof/3`.

Comment: @DanielRocaLopez: It is not the same, if there is no solution - e.g. `L = []`: `findall/3` will find `[]` but `bagof/3` will fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake, I had to put both goals between brackets:

findall(clause, (goal, goal2), C)